# Is there a way to determine if a function is running in document ready or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to determine if a function is running in document ready?

I mean something like this:

```
function myfunction() {
    var isinside = //... what to write here?
    if (isinside) {
    }
}
```

(It is also possible my (very beginner) concept is not optimal, so I write what I am trying to achieve:

I would like to create a reusable object, what can instantiated in multiple instances within a page (hopefully with one line of JavaScript per instance). However there are things what this object must do in document ready, like attaching event handlers.)

Comment: So are you trying to find whether the document ready event has fired yet or not?

Comment: Qantas: Good point. If I use TrueBlueAussie's solution, I have to find out whether the document ready has fired or not. If yes, then I can not rely on the async jQuery .ready handler, instead I must call my init code directly...

Comment: In fact you don't need to check, see the jQuery documentation: [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Can you please explain this comment: `I have to find out whether the document ready has fired or not`? What are you trying to do that requires something different to the patterns already in use for jQuery? Can you show a larger sample of your code?

Comment: I suggest you post your full code to [codereview.se] for advice on how to choose a better pattern. I strongly suspect you're trying to solve a problem that would have a much simpler solution.

Comment: Juhana: There is no code yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you have a problem here? The calling code is normally responsible for being in a DOM ready handler, or not, not the functions.

You *can* just put a DOM ready *redundantly* inside any function, if needed, but this sounds like an odd situation so you need to show the rest of the code.

e.g. any function can have a DOM ready handler:

```
function myfunction() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
         // I am inside DOM ready!
         // Connect my DOM element events here
    });
    // Do my other non-element stuff here
}
```

or, shorter:

```
function myfunction() {
    $(function(){
         // I am inside DOM ready!
         // Connect my DOM element events here
    });
    // Do my other non-element stuff here
}
```

The key here is that DOM ready handlers can be called after DOM ready and they fire immediately.

The downside to this is that you cannot rely on a return value as DOM ready is potentially async.

Comment: He wants to know if his function was called from code inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Barmar: I get that, but why would he *conditionally* care? :)

Comment: TrueBlueAussie: Well the problem is my beginner knowledge what is currently preventing me to use the possibilities  creatively :-). However your solution raises a new question. Now I have to find out whether the document ready has already fired or not. If yes, then I can not rely on the async jQuery .ready handler, instead I must call my init code directly...

Comment: @g.pickardou: You need to show the rest of your code, as your description of how you are doing the rest does not sound correct.

Comment: Got it: "The key here is that DOM ready handlers can be called after DOM ready and they fire immediately" Thx